# How to get and write data with SQLite in Android

Tags: android, sqlite, listview

I am trying to use SQLite for getting and setting data for a listview. My list must have initial data and user must able to edit it.

I created an Item class

```
public final class Items implements BaseColumns {
public static final String TABLE_NAME = "items";

public static final String COLUMN_NAME_TYPE= "itemType";
public static final String COLUMN_NAME_NAME = "itemName";
public static final String COLUMN_NAME_CALORIE = "calorie";


private long id = -1;
private String name;
private String type;
private int calorie;

public String getType() {
    return type;
}

public void setType(String type) {
    this.type = type;
}

public Items(String type,String name, int score) {
    this.name = name;
    this.type=type;
    this.calorie = calorie;

}
public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public int getCalorie() {
    return calorie;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public void setId(long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public void setCalorie(int calorie) {
    this.calorie = calorie;
}


public long getId() {
    return id;
}


public String toString() {
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    builder.append("Item [id=");
    builder.append(id);
    builder.append(", name=");
    builder.append(name);
    builder.append(", calorie=");
    builder.append(calorie);
    builder.append("]");
    return builder.toString();
}
```

}

Then I created a DB helper class which have all the methods that I need. (Note that it is a messy class. While I am struggling to getting data for database I changed lots of things.)

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private static final String DB_NAME = "items.db";
    private static final int DB_VERSION = 1;


    public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DB_NAME, null, DB_VERSION);

    }
    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + Items.TABLE_NAME + " ("
                + Items._ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"
                + Items.COLUMN_NAME_TYPE + " TEXT,"
                + Items.COLUMN_NAME_NAME + " TEXT,"
                + Items.COLUMN_NAME_CALORIE + " INTEGER" + ");");

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + Items.TABLE_NAME);
        onCreate(db);
    }

    public void createItem(Items item) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

        values.put(Items.COLUMN_NAME_NAME, item.getName());
        values.put(Items.COLUMN_NAME_TYPE, item.getName());
        values.put(Items.COLUMN_NAME_CALORIE, item.getCalorie());


        item.setId(db.insert(Items.TABLE_NAME, null, values));
        db.close();
    }


    public Cursor getItemsTypeOf(String type){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        String[] tableColumn=new String[]{Items.COLUMN_NAME_TYPE,  Items.COLUMN_NAME_NAME, Items.COLUMN_NAME_CALORIE};
        String whereClause= Items.COLUMN_NAME_TYPE+"="+type;

     //           +" FROM "+Items.TABLE_NAME
       //         +"WHERE "+Items.COLUMN_NAME_TYPE+"="+type;
        Cursor cur=db.query(Items.TABLE_NAME,tableColumn,whereClause,null,null,null,null);

        return cur;

    }
    public Cursor fetchAllItems() {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

       Cursor cur=  db.query(Items.TABLE_NAME, new String[]{
                        Items.COLUMN_NAME_TYPE, Items.COLUMN_NAME_NAME, Items.COLUMN_NAME_CALORIE,
                }, null, null, null, null,
                Items.COLUMN_NAME_CALORIE + " DESC");
        db.close();
        return cur;

    }
    public Items getItem(long id){

       SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();


        Cursor cursor =
                db.query(Items.TABLE_NAME, 
                        null, 
                        Items._ID+ "=?", 
                        new String[] { String.valueOf(id) }, 
                        null, 
                        null, 
                        null);


        if(cursor!=null&&cursor.moveToFirst()) {
          Items item = new Items(cursor.getString(1), cursor.getString(2),
                    cursor.getInt(3));
            item.setId(cursor.getLong(0));

            cursor.close();


            db.close();;
            return item;
        }
       cursor.close();


        db.close();;
        return null;
    }

}
```

So my application will have categories at mainActivity than each category will parse matched data and show a list of it.

Here is MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        DatabaseHelper dbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(this);
        dbHelper.createItem( new Items("Breakfast","egg",23));



    }
    public void onBreakfastSelected(View view) {
        startActivity(new Intent(this, ListActivity.class));
    }

}
```

And other list class that shows items of category.

```
     public class ListActivity extends Activity implements  AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {


    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_list);

        ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
        list.setOnItemClickListener(this);
        DatabaseHelper dbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(this);
        dbHelper.createItem(new Items("a", "a", 12));

        Items item=dbHelper.getItem(-1);
        //System.out.print();
        adapter.add(item.getName());
        list.setAdapter(adapter);

    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

    }
}
```

I cant get any data that I inserted. It gives me error when I tried to use getItem method. Also I dont know how to seperate Cursor into different datas for parsing them to lists after I get cursor in getItemsTypeOf method.

Comment: What errors you get actually ?

Answer (score 0):

You basically need 5 components.

An activity which displays/uses the layout that includes the ListView. 
You have **ListActivity**.

A layout that includes the ListView. 
You have **activity_list** (I assume as you reference it).

A means of obtaining the data from the database. 
You have **fetchAllItems()**.
Note this, unless you want to introduce complexities, MUST have a column named _id. Although you have the column defined, **fetchAllItems** does not output this column. You could change this to use * (all columns) instead of named columns or include **_ID** as a named column.

A layout for each row/entry/item of the ListView.
You don't appear to have this. It's a pretty simple layout.

Last, you need an appropriate adapter. A Cursor Adapter would be appropriate for a Cursor. There is a simple Cursor Adapater. However, I've never used one. I have always used Custom Cursor Adapters which are quite easy.
You don't appear  to have such an adapter.

I'll add some examples in due course.

Example 1 - **Layout that includes ListView** (I've left a coupe of buttons):-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/aslbc_layout"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="@dimen/standard_dummy_size"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants"
    tools:context="mjt.shopper.ShopListByCursorActivity">
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/standard_button_height"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/standard_dummy_size">
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/aslbcbtn01"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/standard_button_width"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/standard_button_height"
            android:text="@string/standarddonebutton"
            android:textColor="@color/colorNormalButtonText"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:backgroundTint="@color/colorNormalButton"
            android:onClick="aslbcDone">
        </Button>
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/aslbcbtn02"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/standard_button_width"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/standard_button_height"
            android:text="@string/standardaddbuttontext"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textColor="@color/colorNormalButtonText"
            android:backgroundTint="@color/colorNormalButton"
            android:onClick="aslbcAddShop">
        </Button>
    </LinearLayout>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/aslbclv01"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/standard_listview_height"
        android:longClickable="true">
    </ListView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Example 2 - **Layout for each Item (entry or row)** *(Note that I have Visibility set to gone for fields. This is because this is still work in progress and it makes it easy for me to turn them on if I need)*:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/standard_listview_row_height"
    android:padding="0dp"
    android:background="@color/colorlistviewroweven"
    tools:context=".ShopListEntryActivity">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/shop_id_entry"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/standard_dummy_size"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textSize="@dimen/standard_listview_text_size"
        android:textStyle="italic"
        android:visibility="gone"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/shop_name_entry"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/standard_dummy_size"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.3"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textSize="@dimen/standard_listview_text_size"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/shop_order_entry"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/standard_dummy_size"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:textSize="@dimen/standard_listview_text_size"
        android:visibility="gone"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/shop_city_entry"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/standard_dummy_size"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.3"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textSize="@dimen/standard_listview_text_size"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/shop_street_entry"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/standard_dummy_size"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.4"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textSize="@dimen/standard_listview_text_size"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/shop_state_entry"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/standard_dummy_size"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:textSize="@dimen/standard_listview_text_size"
        android:visibility="gone"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/shop_phone_entry"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/standard_dummy_size"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:textSize="@dimen/standard_listview_text_size"
        android:visibility="gone"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/shop_notes_entry"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/standard_dummy_size"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:textSize="@dimen/standard_listview_text_size"
        android:visibility="gone"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Example 3 - **The Custom Cursor Adapter** 
*(Note getView isn't required but left in as you may find the code useful - it alternates the row colours)*
*Note that newView includes (inflates) the list Item layout*

```
class ShopsCursorAdapter extends CursorAdapter {
    public ShopsCursorAdapter(Context context, Cursor cursor, int flags) {
        super(context, cursor, 0);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertview, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = super.getView(position, convertview, parent);
        Context context = view.getContext();
        if (position % 2 == 0) {
            view.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.colorlistviewroweven));
        } else {
            view.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.colorlistviewrowodd));
        }
        return view;
    }
    @Override
    public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
        return LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.activity_shop_list_entry, parent, false);
    }
    @Override
    public void bindView(View view,Context context, Cursor cursor) {
        TextView textviewShopid = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.shop_id_entry);
        TextView textViewShopName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.shop_name_entry);
        //TextView textViewShopOrder = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.shop_order_entry);
        TextView textViewShopStreet = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.shop_street_entry);
        TextView textViewShopCity = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.shop_city_entry);
        //TextView textViewShopState = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.shop_state_entry);
        //TextView textViewShopPhone = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.shop_phone_entry);
        //TextView textViewShopNotes = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.shop_notes_entry);

        textviewShopid.setText(cursor.getString(ShopperDBHelper.SHOPS_COLUMNN_ID_INDEX));
        textViewShopName.setText(cursor.getString(ShopperDBHelper.SHOPS_COLUMN_NAME_INDEX));
        //textViewShopOrder.setText(cursor.getString(ShopperDBHelper.SHOPS_COLUMN_ORDER_INDEX));
        textViewShopStreet.setText(cursor.getString(ShopperDBHelper.SHOPS_COLUMN_STREET_INDEX));
        textViewShopCity.setText(cursor.getString(ShopperDBHelper.SHOPS_COLUMN_CITY_INDEX));
        //textViewShopState.setText(cursor.getString(ShopperDBHelper.SHOPS_COLUMN_STATE_INDEX));
        //textViewShopPhone.setText(cursor.getString(ShopperDBHelper.SHOPS_COULMN_PHONE_INDEX));
        //textViewShopNotes.setText(cursor.getString(ShopperDBHelper.SHOPS_COULMN_NOTES_INDEX));
    }
}
```

Example 4 - The onCreate part of the Activity that uses the ListView :-

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_shop_list_by_cursor);

        shoplistcursor = shopperdb.getShopsAsCursor();
        final ListView listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.aslbclv01);
        final ShopsCursorAdapter adapter = new ShopsCursorAdapter(this,shoplistcursor, CursorAdapter.FLAG_REGISTER_CONTENT_OBSERVER);
        listview.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Note **shoplistcursor** is defined in the class by (increases the scope):-

```
public Cursor shoplistcursor;
```

`shoplistcursor = shopperdb.getShopsAsCursor();` would be along the lines of `mycursor = DatabaseHelper.fetchAllItems();` in your case.

The following is **getShopsAsCursor** :-

```
    public Cursor getShopsAsCursor() {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        String sqlstr = "SELECT * FROM " + SHOPS_TABLE_NAME +
                " ORDER BY " + SHOPS_COLUMN_NAME + ", " + SHOPS_COLUMN_CITY + ";";
        return db.rawQuery(sqlstr,null);
    }
```

In the adapter, (example 3), **SHOPS_COLUMN_????_INDEX** equates to the offset of the respective cursor column e.g. **_id** is the first column in the table, it's offset is **0**, so **SHOPS_COLUMN_ID_INDEX** equates to 0. **name** is the column in the table, so **SHOPS_COLUMN_NAME_INDEX** equates to **1**.

---

That is Stage 1 it doesn't allow you to Edit or Add. I'd suggest getting the list working first. However, you may have noted that in the layout for example 1 there are two buttons one, the Done button, acts like back (ie the code just does **finish()**). The second, the Add button, allows an new entry to be added by starting another activity with a layout that has TextEdits for inputting new data.

As for Editting; existing data the code, not shown in the in example 4, includes an onItemCLicked listener and code that then allows the row data to be edited (this actually uses the same activity and layout that adjusts accordingly).  It also includes an onItemLongClick that can delete the selected row.

I can amended this question when you are ready. Simply comment that you are ready including @MikeT in the comment.